# Linux bash: How can I use the eval command correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can run the following command on the Linux command line and it correctly lists all the files that have the ABC- and XYZ- prefixes:

```
    ls {ABC-,XYZ-}*.xml

    Result: ABC-01.xml  ABC-02.xml  ABC-03.xml  XYZ-01.xml  XYZ-02.xml
```

Now, I figured that I could use a variable as follows:

```
    file_pfx={ABC-,XYZ-}
```

and then use the variable in the "ls" command combined with "eval":

```
    eval 'ls ${file_pfx}*.xml'

    Result: ls: {ABC-,XYZ-}*.xml: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can't store the braced expressioni in a variable because brace expansion takes place *before* parameter substitution. See the [order of expansions in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions).

Comment: Before actually using `eval`, see ["Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: Thanks for including a complete test case with output! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *double quotes* to allow variable expansion (`$file_pfx`):

```
eval "ls ${file_pfx}*.xml"
```

Notice I'm assuming your filenames don't contain spaces.

Anyway, be careful with the use of `eval`.

Comment: It will not work if any of the filenames contains a space

Answer (score 4):

Don't use eval. You can use extended globbing instead:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
prefix='ABC-|XYZ-'
ls @($prefix)*.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to use an array

```
$ touch ABC-01.xml  ABC-02.xml  ABC-03.xml  XYZ-01.xml  XYZ-02.xml

$ files=( {ABC-,XYZ-}*.xml )

$ printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"
ABC-01.xml
ABC-02.xml
ABC-03.xml
XYZ-01.xml
XYZ-02.xml
```